# Generic System.Windows.WeakEventManager class?

Tags: c#

Is there any generic weakeventmanager class available?. if not is there any known Weakevent class and sample implementation?.

Comment: Are you looking for the [System.Windows.WeakEventManager Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.weakeventmanager.aspx)?

Comment: yes. how can i create a generic WeakEventManager class?

Comment: Have a look at the *Notes to Inheritors* in the *Remarks* section of the linked page.

Answer (score 1):

look at this:
[Generic WeakEvent Manager & Listener](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl/wpf/thread/413dfedd-4e45-4629-bd73-67cc4c18ef35)

Answer (score 1):

There is now a generic version as of .NET v4.5:

- [WeakEventManager<TEventSource, TEventArgs> Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh199438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)